# Regex is accepting P@ssW0rd as password when it shouldn't

Tags: regex

**Note:** It seems that I have to stick to a one liner for the regular expression, Due to the validation library I'm using ([jquery validation engine](http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/demos/demoValidators.html))

I have the following regex:

```
((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?!^1{1,5}[a-z]+$).{8,25})$
```

Which matches the following:

```
Minimun of 8 characters
1 lowercase character
1 uppercase character
1 digit
1 special character
```

The problem here is that it accepts:
**P@ssW0rd** and **Qw3rty*** as valid passwords.

The above shouldn't pass validation. I came up with these two expressions to try and  work around this but have not been successful at incorporating it to the final piece.

```
p[a@][s5]{2}w[o0]rd  // anything with password in it including leet variants
qw[e3]rty            // anything with qwerty in it including leet variant
```

**Rule should be: Don't allow any variant of Password or Qwerty at the beginning of the word or end**.

Any idea on how to put these together and make it work?

Comment: You're going to have to check after the initial regex has matched as a valid password, I don't think you can put that into the same regex.

Comment: Is the question actually "How to forbid these words in my regex" ?

Comment: @Kilazur Yes, trying to avoid variants of "password", "qwerty"

Comment: By what rule `P@ssW0rd` should not be allowed in your regex?

Comment: @anubhava Check my updated question. I wish to block  variants of password/qwerty from being used at the beginning or end of the password.

Comment: Please if you down-voted, explain why??

Comment: No I didn't down vote and I rarely do.

Comment: @anubhava Wasn't refering to you directly anubhava :) sorry if it seemed that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you add more negative look-ahead clauses as follows?

```
(?!p[a@][s5]{2}w[o0]rd) // prevents variants of "password"
(?!qw[e3]rty)           // prevents variants of "qwerty"
```

... to get (also adding in the start anchor):

```
^((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?!^1{1,5}[a-z]+$)(?!p[a@][s5]{2}w[o0]rd)(?!qw[e3]rty).{8,25})$
```

This may not quite work as you want, however - in order to ensure there's upper-case characters you'll have to match in a *case-sensitive* manner, but your expressions for "password" and "qwerty" will only work if you match in a *case-insensitive* manner. You probably need to change this to the following:

```
^((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?!^1{1,5}[a-z]+$)(?![pP][aA@][sS5]{2}[wW][oO0][rR][dD])(?![qQ][wW][e3][rR][tT][yY]).{8,25})$
```

Yuck!

To be honest, I'd recommend a more fundamental rethink of your strategy.

- You can try to blacklist "obvious" passwords - but you're never going to catch all of them. What about "@5dfgHjkl"? Whatever you try to ban, a user will be able to contrive something that's "obvious" but allowed.
- For every extra thing you ban you'll need to come up with an error message that explains to your customers what's wrong with their choice of password. They aren't going to enjoy trying to second-guess your validation function.
- Despite your attempt at enforcing password strength, it probably doesn't help against common dictionary attacks which combine a leet-speak word with numeric suffix.

If you want to try and encourage stronger passwords, why not include a visual display of the current password strength so your customers can see what's wrong with their password? You won't even have to write the code: there are plenty of plugins online.

Comment: I got it working with your example, and thank you for the recommendation they make perfect sense and will be looking into the password strength plugins.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a 'blacklist' in Regex using the following format:

```
blacklisted_exp_1|blacklisted_exp_2| ... (original_expression)
```

The entire expression will match when any of the blacklisted expressions match, but the original expression capture group will only match if all the blacklisted expressions fail to match.

In your case this would be:

```
qw[e3]rty|P[a@][s5]{2}W[o0]rd|((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?!^1{1,5}[a-z]+$).{8,25})$
```

Here's a more simple example which you can try in the web console:

```
var regex = /foo|bar|([a-z]{3})/; // Matches all 3-letter words except foo and bar

"foo".match(regex); // ["foo", undefined]
"bar".match(regex); // ["bar", undefined]
"baz".match(regex); // ["baz", "baz"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add negative lookahead in your regex:

```
^((?=.*?\d)(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[A-Z])(?!p[a@][s5]{2}w[o0]rd$)(?!qw[e3]rty).{8,25})$
```

#### [Regex Demo](http://regex101.com/r/fZ6vW1/1)